# Cross compiling QT and example program does not find platform

Tags: pi-2, ubuntu, cross-compilation, qt, linaro

I followed the follwoing guide to cross-compile QT 5.6 on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine for the raspberrypi2 running jessie:
https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS#A_modern_guide_for_cross-compiling_Qt_5.6_for_HW_accelerated_OpenGL_with_eglfs_on_Raspbian_Jessie_and_setting_up_Qt_Creator

Everything works fine, with no errors during compiling, but when I try to run the example program (qopenglwidget, step 12 of the guide) I get the following error: "This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "eglfs" in """.

I checked that in /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/platforms there exists a libqeglfs.so. What can I do to make it work?

Edit: I forgot to include some relevant information: I did not connect the raspberry via hdmi but use the RaspberryPi Touch Display which is connected via the DSI port (https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-touch-display/)

Edit2: I also tried a different program which was built with cmake, but there the same problem occurs.

Thanks for your help!